# file contents(html) never loads

Tags: php

I am tried to get the html source of a page located on this url `http://www4.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=3261368&boxtag=3314&sec=onliners`  I used `curl` `file_get_contents` and `fopen` which all work fine on my hosting plan. When I try to use this on a godaddy hosted website it does do anything and just shows the loading icon. I contacted customer service and they told me I need to alter my code so that it will work on their servers. Is there an alternative method other than those listen above.

Comment: maybe you will be nice and show us that code

Comment: Please consider improving your question. Your question in its current form does not contain enough details. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section on ways to improve your question.

Comment: I think we need to see the code you are using. Do you get ANY data when you try to get the page using curl or what do you get? Prehaps Godaddy blocks communication with external servers?

Comment: Keep in mind that fopen wrappers need to be enabled for you to use `file_get_contents` and `fopen` on urls

Comment: Read and re-read http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this as an alternative http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://seekeronos.blogsome.com/2007/09/13/phoogle-and-godaddy-a-work-around/), cURL works fine on Godaddy.

`allow_url_fopen` is probably disabled for security reasons, to avoid common vulnerabilities on poorly designed scripts. This does affect [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an alternative method other than those listen above.

Apart from opening a socket, inputting the request and parsing the output -- no. The methods you've described are the only viable possibilities to read content from an external source using PHP. If cURL is enabled, it should indeed work as Benjamin already described. Godaddy itself [claims to support cURL](http://help.godaddy.com/article/5614?ci=8058).